# ng-options and ng-bind not working with objects and strings

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a drop down bound to `ng-options` (which uses an array of objects)
and `ng-bind` (which uses a string). This doesn't work because object comparison fails. Is there a workaround for this?

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="Person.Gender"
        ng-options="a.name for a in dropdowns.gender">
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken what you want is to bind the name property to the person.gender property of the $scope. What you need to do is:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="Person.Gender"
        ng-options="a.name as a.name for a in dropdowns.gender">
</select>
```

The first part defines what is actually stored in the ng-model and the second part how is going to display, in this case both displayed value and model value are the same.

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zaq9/)

Comment: I missed a.name as a.name